# Transform nested dictionary key values to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I would like extract those nested dictionaries in the "dic" column and transform them into PySpark dataframe. Like this:

[image]

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.show() #sample dataframe

+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|timestmap|dic                                                                                                       |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|timestamp|{"Name":"David","Age":"25","Location":"New York","Height":"170","fields":{"Color":"Blue","Shape":"round"}}|
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For **`Spark2.4+`**, you could use **`from_json`** and **`schema_of_json`**.

```
schema=df.select(F.schema_of_json(df.select("dic").first()[0])).first()[0]


df.withColumn("dic", F.from_json("dic", schema))\
  .selectExpr("dic.*").selectExpr("*","fields.*").drop("fields").show()

#+---+------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
#|Age|Height|Location| Name|Color|Shape|
#+---+------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
#| 25|   170|New York|David| Blue|round|
#+---+------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
```

You could also use **`rdd`** way with **`read.json`** if you don't have **`spark2.4`**. There will be performance hit of **`df to rdd`** conversion.

```
df1 = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.dic))\
   
df1.select(*[x for x in df1.columns if x!='fields'], F.col("fields.*")).show()

#+---+------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
#|Age|Height|Location| Name|Color|Shape|
#+---+------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
#| 25|   170|New York|David| Blue|round|
#+---+------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get the schema without having to manually construct it? (the json I provided above is just sample data. I have at least 1000 fields in my real data).

Comment: you could use schema_of_json function to do that for you, as shown in my edited answer above. the only thing is schema_of_json only accepts a string literal so we have to collect a row string and pass it to the function. the catch here is that the row you are collecting should have all the fields in it

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just realized that my data actually has 3 levels of nesting. Using your solution I can only get the the second level How can I approach the third level from here? (I have edited in my question)